# Extract html block based on tag, class and string content

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am really new to bf4 and I would like to get specific content from an html page.
When I try the following code, I will get many results having the same tag and class. So I need to filter more. There is a string content into the block I am interested in. Is there a way to additionally scrape also by content? Any contribution is appreciated.

```
html_doc = requests.get('https://www.blockchain.com/bch/address/qqe2tae7hfga2zj5jj8mtjsgznjpy5rvyglew4cy8m')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find_all('span', class_='sc-1ryi78w-0 gCzMgE sc-16b9dsl-1 kUAhZx u3ufsr-0 fGQJzg'))
```

Edit:

I should add that the content look like the following. So the there is a string for which I want to extract the value but the value is in the next tag. Here I want to extract 3.79019103 which is under the string 'Final Balance'.

```
          Total Sent
         </span>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="sc-8sty72-0 kcFwUU">
        <span class="sc-1ryi78w-0 gCzMgE sc-16b9dsl-1 kUAhZx u3ufsr-0 fGQJzg" opacity="1">
         13794.11698089 BCH
        </span>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="sc-1enh6xt-0 jqiNji">
       <div class="sc-8sty72-0 kcFwUU">
        <div>
         <span class="sc-1ryi78w-0 gCzMgE sc-16b9dsl-1 kUAhZx sc-1n72lkw-0 lhmHll" opacity="1">
          Final Balance
         </span>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="sc-8sty72-0 kcFwUU">
        <span class="sc-1ryi78w-0 gCzMgE sc-16b9dsl-1 kUAhZx u3ufsr-0 fGQJzg" opacity="1">
         3.79019103 BCH
        </span>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: You should look at regular expressions. Here is the python library for it, but there are many more: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: @luthervespers - will that help him reduce his BS output, or can he only apply regex after he gets back more results from BS than he really wants?  I think he's asking for the former.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For finding the Final Balance tag:

```py
final_balance_tag = next(x for x in soup.find_all('span') if 'Final Balance' in x.text)
```

With this tag you may just jump to the next span tag.

```py
final_balance_tag.findNext('span')
```

Which gives

```html
<span class="sc-1ryi78w-0 gCzMgE sc-16b9dsl-1 kUAhZx u3ufsr-0 fGQJzg" opacity="1">
         3.79019103 BCH
        </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Search for  the string `Final Balance` using the `text= <your string>` parameter.
2. Get the next tag using `find_next()`, which returns the first match.
3. Use a list comprehension to filter the output only if it `isdigit()`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.blockchain.com/bch/address/qqe2tae7hfga2zj5jj8mtjsgznjpy5rvyglew4cy8m'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL).content, 'html.parser')

price = soup.find(text=lambda t: "Final" in t).find_next(text=True)

print("".join([t for t in price if t.isdigit()]))
```

Output (currently):

```
000000000
```